# How to preserve parent function's variable value before creating local variable with the same name?

Tags: javascript

I have a local table variable in the function, and a child function that's supposed to have a variable with the same name, while still being able to access parent's variable. This should be obvious and straightforward, but, unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't let me access parent's variable if I define a local variable with the same name anywhere:

```
var p = {alpha : 'beta'};

console.debug (p);
// [08:16:21.896] ({alpha:"beta"})
// Okay.

(function() {
    console.debug (p);
    // [08:16:21.896] ({alpha:"beta"})
    // Right! JavaScript, you're so awesome!
})();

// One moment though, I think I still need the parent's table...
(function() {
    var p = { 'p': p };
    console.debug (p);
    // [08:16:21.896] ({p:(void 0)})
    // Wait, what?
})();

// Okay, maybe giving it the same name in the same statement confuses you?
(function() {
    var parent_p = p;
    var p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
    // [08:16:21.897] undefined
})();
// Give me back my variable! http://v.gd/jsWhyDoYouDoThis
```

What's going on there? Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Why does it have to have the same name? Can you access window.p or whatever the node equivalent is if you're running node? Anyway, variable hoisting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although JavaScript looks like C, Java and others, they have **block-level scope**. JavaScript has **function-level scope**.

So in JavaScript an `if` statement does not create a new block. Only functions do. On top of that, `var`iable and `function` declarations are "hoisted" (invisibly moved) to the top of the block. That's the reason of your problem.

When you define a variable:

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    var x = 1;
}
```

is actually interpreted like:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    bar();
    x = 1;
}
```

So if you read a varible `x` in `bar()`, even if it is defined in a higher scope (outside `foo()`), it reads `foo()`'s `x`, which is `undefined` when `bar()` is executed.

Taking a closer look at your code, trying to understand what happens in practice:

```
var p = {alpha : 'beta'};
...    
(function() {
    // var p = { 'p': p }; actually is:
    var p;
    p = { 'p': p }; // thus p inside is `undefined`
    console.debug (p);
})();

(function() {
    // var parent_p = p; var p = {};  actually is:
    var parent_p, p;
    parent_p = p; // that's why parent_p becomes undefined here
    p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this in standard ECMAScript.

A `var` declaration anywhere inside a block is a directive to the JS parser that all use of the named variable in that block refers to a local variable. In JS, a block for this purpose is the surrounding function, or global if not in a function definition(*).

Consequently in your last example you are assigning `parent_p` with the value of the local variable `p`, which as you haven't assigned it anything yet is `undefined`.

You would have to use an intermediate scope to save the reference if you absolutely must reuse the variable name:

```
(function() {
    var parent_p = p;
    (function() {
        var p = {};
        console.debug (parent_p);
    })();
})();
```

A future revision of ECMAScript is likely to pick up the Mozilla JS extension `let` which introduces smaller blocks for definitions than functions. This would let you spell this more simply:

```
(function() {
    var parent_p = p;
    let (p = {}) {
        console.debug (parent_p);
    }
})();
```

Another common approach is to pass the variable in as an argument:

```
(function(parent_p) {
    var p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
})(p);
```

(*: You can read variables from the global scope using the global object - ie `window.p` - but you can't get local variables from enclosing non-global scopes.)

Comment: Is that how Mozilla implemented `let` so far? I thought it should be used like `{ let p = {}; console.log (parent_p); }` (this works in node/v8 with --harmony --use-strict; your version doesn't).

Comment: Both syntaxes (mine is a 'let statement'; yours is a 'let definition') should work (and do for me in Firefox 20).

Comment: The "statements" and "expressions" do work in Firefox, but I'm wondering if that's Mozilla-specific. They don't work on node, and I couldn't find them in the current ES6 draft (where the "definitions" seem to be called "declarations"). I still have a lot to read and learn from the drafts though.

Answer (score 1):

As alternate view on acdcjunior's correct answer:

Due to function scope (no block-scope) and hoisting, this:

```
(function() {
    var parent_p = p;
    var p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
    // [08:16:21.897] undefined
})();
```

becomes:

```
(function() {
    var parent_p, p;  //both undefined
    parent_p = p;     //undefined
    p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
    // [08:16:21.897] undefined
})();
```

So to solve this, you'd access the variable as property of the object that contains it; in this case `window` is the 'host'/'root' object that holds `p` as one of it's direct properties.

```
(function() {
    var parent_p = window.p,
               p = {};
    console.debug (parent_p);
    // [08:16:21.897] ({alpha:"beta"})
})();
```