# How to access parent function's local variables?

Tags: javascript, scope, dynamic-variables

let's say i have this function

```
var foo = function ()
{
  var bar = true;
  var inner = function ()
  {
    alert(bar);
  }();
}
```

when I run this, everything is okay, alert says 'true'. But what if the variable name is dynamic and I have to get the value of bar from a string? How can I access the parent scope to get the variable?

example: if the scope is window and we have the string containing name of a dynamic variable, I would use window[someString] to get that variable.

I'm guessing I'll need this same approach in my problem too, but I don't know what object to use as a parent object.

Comment: I don't think you can't do this, using an object seems like the right approach.

Comment: This link should help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438006/how-to-preserve-parent-functions-variable-value-before-creating-local-variable

Answer (score -1):

There is no parent object, as the variables are not properties of any object.

You can use the `eval` function to get the value of a variable from a string containing the name. Example:

```
var foo = function ()
{
  var bar = true;
  var inner = function ()
  {
    var name = "bar";
    alert(eval(name));
  }();
}
```

Word of caution:

- The `eval` function is slow, as it has to parse the string into code each time.
- The `eval` function is **dangerous** as it will execute anything the string contains. If the string can contain anything that a different user has control over, it may open up your site for cross site scripting.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.